# Creating file in jar

Tags: java, jar, pdf-generation

At a certain moment in my program I'm creating a pdf File with iText.  This File is created so people can see it an also added to my database.  It works just fine in Eclipse but when I make a runnable jar it doesn't work.  The file is not created and not added to the database.  I have no idea why it's not working in a jar.

```
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream(documentName.getName() + ".pdf"));
```

///////

```
        File file = new File(document.getName() + ".pdf");
```

Any suggestions anyone?  thx all

Comment: Since you just use the documents name to create the file, you create it in your current working directory which does not have to be the same directory your jar is in. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: *"Creating file in jar"*  A Jar is typically 'read only'.

Comment: The specific location is not that important.  I just use the current working directory as a example.

Comment: Did you catch any Exception that we do not see in your code snippet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to do this:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("C:\\some_file.pdf"));
```

and check whether file exists on c drive as some_file. I believe it will. Additionally, I do not know what kind of object is document, but maybe it contains method that returns absolute path.

Edit:
If you use that file again in one program I would do this different:

```
File file = new File(document.getName() + ".pdf");
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream(file));
```

or even

```
String path = "some/safe/path/maybe/provided/by/user"; // in settings or sth
File file = new File(path+document.getName() + ".pdf");
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream(file));
```

Comment: could you post whole function? or send it in private? It doesn't seem that problem occurs in my code. Or I can send you my jar file, and if it does work than we will be able to figure it out

Comment: Any luck? If you solved it, post solution, maybe someone else could take advantage of this, and I am curious too.

Answer (score 1):

try creating the .jar with [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) this will add the libs you're using to the created .jar

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative file path names (?). So it could be that your file get saved in diferent locations (folders) if running from Eclipse or from the Jar.

Your file always get saved in System.getProperty("user.dir").

Comment: True, but I'm using them all the time so depending from where I run it.  I will save and get the file at the specific location.